# Is $TT^*$ (or $T^*T$) densely defined if $T$ is densely defined and symmetric?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Is $TT^*$ (or $T^*T$) densely defined if $T$ is a densely defined and symmetric linear operator?

I feel this is untrue, but do you have a counterexample?

Thanks

Comment: It is true if $T$ is closed.

Comment: Yes,  QuantumSpace, I know. Thanks, but I need an answer for a symmetric $T$.

Comment: Let me remind you that I already have a counterexample when $T$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Also, it is plain that for a counterexample we must avoid a $T$ for which $T^2$ is densely defined.

Comment: @Mohammed Hichem Mortad do you have a reference for the proof of the claim that $T^*T$ is densely defined and self-adjoint, if T is densely defined and closed?

Comment: E.g., in Schmudgen's book...

Answer (score 0):

An answer has been found, see

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022247X23001622

A PDF version can be found below:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.04812.pdf